# How to call magento2 SOAP or REST API outside magento2?

Tags: magento2, soap, rest-api

I am using below code to call the API but its showing error:

```
$request = new SoapClient(
    'http://magento2-dev.local/index.php/soap/? wsdl&services=foggylineSliderSlideRepositoryV1',
    array(
        'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2,
        'stream_context' => stream_context_create(array(
                'http' => array(
                    'header' => 'Authorization: Bearer pk8h93nq9cevaw55bohkjbp0o7kpl4d3'
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
$response = $request->foggylineSliderSlideRepositoryV1GetById(array('slideId' => 1));
var_dump($response);
```

Comment: What is you error ?

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

//Authentication rest API magento2.Please change url accordingly your url
$adminUrl = 'http://localhost/magentoce27/index.php/rest/V1/integration/admin/token';
$ch = curl_init();
$data = array("username" => "adminuser", "password" => "pwd");
$data_string = json_encode($data);

$ch = curl_init($adminUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
);

$token = curl_exec($ch);
$token = json_decode($token);
```

With this code also u can get access token dynamically and try to integrate it in above code

Answer (score 1):

Here is demo for curl for rest using token.  
Token you need to generate from admin System->Integration and configure in code below. 
 For demo purpose I have made below rest default customer call.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

/*Token Generated from SYstem Integration*/

$token = '4hmpioj8qvtgh1d06ujgg52a52yqbmye' (This is token generated from system integration);
$rest_url = 'http://localhost/magentoce27/index.php/rest/V1/customers/1';
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,$rest_url);

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
$headers[] = 'Authorization: Bearer '.$token;

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec ($curl);

echo "<pre>"; print_r($result);
?>
```

Comment: I am trying to create integration its generating  Consumer Key, Consumer Secret but Access Token field showing empty.

Comment: This code will allow you to generate dynamic access token.

Comment: It gave : {"message":"No such entity with %fieldName = %fieldValue","parameters":{"fieldName":"customerId","fieldValue":1}}

Answer (score 1):

To call SOAP API outside Magento 2:

step1:
app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/Product.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Model;
use Vendor\Module\Api\ProductInterface;

class Product extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel implements ProductInterface{


    public function __construct( 
        .......
    ){
        .......
    }

    /**
    *
    * @param int|null $store.
    * @return string options in a json format. 
    */
    public function addTemplateProducts($store){
        return 'store:'.$store;//.json_encode($arg_list);
    }
}
?>
```

step:2
app/code/Vendor/Module/Api/ProductInterface.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Api;

interface ProductInterface
{
    /**
    *
    * @param int|null $store.
    * @return string options in a json format. 
    */
    public function addTemplateProducts($store);
}
?>
```

step3:
app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/webapi.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../app/code/Magento/Webapi/etc/webapi.xsd">
    <route url="/V1/product/addTemplateProducts" method="POST">
        <service class="Vendor\Module\Api\ProductInterface" method="addTemplateProducts"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="anonymous"/>
        </resources>
    </route>
</routes>
```

step4:
your-magento-base-url.com/soapTest.php

```
<?php
    define('BASEPATH','http://localhost/magento21/');
    error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);//ini_set('display_errors',1);//error_reporting(0);


    $token = 'tf4ti4s8jjbt7jtpaxh9k2ex8txdf2vs';// Your Integration access token



    require_once('vendor/zendframework/zend-server/src/Client.php');
    require_once('vendor/zendframework/zend-soap/src/Client.php');
    require_once('vendor/zendframework/zend-soap/src/Client/Common.php');
    ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", 0);

    $opts = array('http' => array('header' => "Authorization: Bearer " . $token));
    $context = stream_context_create($opts);

    $wsdlUrl = BASEPATH."soap?wsdl&services=vendorModuleProductV1";
    $param = array('store'=>2);
    try{
        $soapClient = new \Zend\Soap\Client($wsdlUrl);
        $soapClient->setSoapVersion(SOAP_1_2);//SOAP_1_1 or SOAP_1_2
        $soapClient->setStreamContext($context);

        $soapResponse = $soapClient->vendorModuleProductV1MethodName($param);
        print_r($soapResponse);
    }catch(Exception $e){
        //echo 'Error : '.$e->getMessage();
        //echo '<br />'.$e->getTraceAsString();
        echo '<br />'.$e->__toString();
        //echo '<br />'.$e->getFile();echo '<br />'.$e->getLine();
        //print_r($e->getTrace());
        //var_dump($e->getCode());
    }
```

Now run your-magento-base-url.com/soapTest.php in the browser and you will see

```
stdClass Object
(
    [result] => store:2
)
```

I'll update this answer regarding REST call outside Magento 2 soon.

The above worked fine for me. So check and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

What error does it show?

The url pattern for the soap calls should be something like this

```
/soap/default?wsdl=1&services=foggylineSliderSliderRepositoryV1
```

You can get a list of available services like this

```
/soap/default?wsdl_list=1
```

Comment: it is showing below error:
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://magento2-dev.local/index.php/soap/? wsdl&services=foggylineSliderSlideRepositoryV1' : failed to load external entity "http://magento2-dev.local/index.php/soap/?%20wsdl&services=foggylineSliderSlideRepositoryV1" in /vagrant/pub/index/index.php:21 Stack trace: #0 /vagrant/pub/index/index.php(21): SoapClient->SoapClient('http://magento2...', Array) #1 {main} thrown in /vagrant/pub/index/index.php on line 21

Comment: I think it might be the /default? part being missing from the url.